# Power BI to Big Query errors when creating new projects

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, powerquery

In my company we are using Big Query as our DW and visualize the data in Power BI. We are experiencing an issue where whenever our backend devs spins up a new project, PBI throws an error because the user does not have bigquery.jobs.create in the new project.

Even if I specify a project in the PBI connector, I am returned with all of the projects within our tenant and it seems like my access then defaults to the lowest available level.

How can I from PBI shield myself from trying to read projects I don't want to read from and just connect to the relevant project I specify?

Alternatively, can we do something different in our BQ setup where devs can spin up projects without affecting our PBI setup?